# SecurityGuard connections to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012

I am integrating SecurityGuard into my C# MS-MVC4 project.  (SG link: https://github.com/kahanu/Security-Guard)  We are using a database-first approach, and have already established a user table.

I have set `connectionString` to point to the project database, and copied the connection name everywhere that needs it.

However, I have found no documentation on how to connect to the database.  The most I've found is "Run MVC Installer", but that threw this:

`Error creating Role: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.

So how do I link up SecurityGuard and the project?

Also, I want to know what fields to put into the `Role` table used by SG.  Again, I have found no documentation on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I (or MVC Installer) put the following settings in `web.config`, inside `<system.web>`:

```
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="MembershipConnection" applicationName="(Application)" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="MembershipConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="(Application)" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="MembershipConnection" applicationName="(Application)" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Then I set connectionStringName to my desired connection.  The code-first pattern then created the standard Membership provider tables.